# Best practices for changing REST API server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a dilemma: I had created a simple Javascript application that uses a Rails REST API. Variables in Ruby were declared according to their best practices: snake/underline case. In that way, the data received from the client-app, is in that format.
Now, I want to use another framework for server, ASP.NET. The problem is that the best practices for variables in C# is PascalCase (upper cammelCase). I don't want to change too much code in the Javascript app, but I  wouldn't like to "break" the best practices.

What should I do?
What's the best practice or the best way?

Is there a simple way to interprete underline_case, and parse it to PascalCase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, there are methods which specifically accomplish this.

They come from the `activesupport` gem.

Install then, then `require active_support/all`.

Then try the following methods:

1. `"PascalCase".underscore` will return pascal_case
2. `"underline_case".camelize` will return UnderlineCase

This is included by default in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

In Kaltura we generate an XML descriptor of each API server, see example: http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/api_schema.php

We have different servers written in different coding languages so we had to deal with the same issue.

We decided that internally different servers will implement according to their coding standard but the REST API offers a different path to each one of the controllers and actions and the objects and their properties are named externally according to common standard.

To align with each client side language, we generate a different client library for each coding language according to its standard, see the generator: https://github.com/kaltura/clients-generator, you can use it yourself.

For more server guidelines, see my blog: http://restafar.com/create-new-rest-server/